# Let $P(z)$be a polynomial and let $C$ be the circle $\mid z-a\mid$=$R$. Calculate the integral respect to the conjugate of z.

Tags: complex-analysis

My complex class now finished Cauchy Integral Formula, Reflection Principle, and Residue Formula, and I am asked to show:

Let $P(z)$be a polynomial and let $C$ be the circle $\mid z-a\mid$=$R$.

Show $\int_{C}$$P(z)d\bar{z}=-2\pi iR^{2}P^{'}(a)$.

Here is my thought:

Since it related to $2\pi i$ and $P^{'}(a)$, I think it must be related to Cauchy Integral Formula, also since we have to integral respect to the conjugate of $z$, and the circle is symmetric respect to the real axis, I think it may be related to the Reflection Principle

So I let $P(z)=a_{n}z^{n}+\cdots+a_{1}z+a_{0}$, since $P(z)$ is a polynomial. Then, we have to deal with different cases about $R$.

If $R\geq a$, then $0$ is inside $C$, we can apply Cauchy Integral Formula.

Let $f(\zeta) = a_{n}\zeta^{n+1}+\cdots+a_{1}\zeta^{2}+a_{0}\zeta$.

Then $\int_{C}$$P(z)d{z}$ = $\int_{C}$$\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-0}$ = $2\pi i f(0)=0$

And I don't know how to proceed further. This result is not right since I did not even consider the conjugate of $z$, since I don't know how to consider it.

Also, I don't know how to deal with the case $R\leq a$, since in that case, Cauchy Integral Formula is not this easy to use again.

Any hints and detailed explanations are really appreciated! Also, this question is due next Wednesday, and we have class on Monday, so if you think I should use other theorems, please feel free to tell me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$|z-a|^{2}=R^{2}$, $(z-a)(\overline{z}-\overline{a})=R^{2}$, so $d(z-a)(\overline{z}-\overline{a})=0$, or $(\overline{z}-\overline{a})dz+(z-a)d\overline{z}=0$, so $d\overline{z}=-\dfrac{\overline{z-a}}{z-a}dz$, hence
\begin{align*}
\int_{C}P(z)d\overline{z}&=-\int_{C}P(z)\dfrac{\overline{z-a}}{z-a}dz\\
&=-\int_{0}^{1}P'(a)(Re^{2\pi i\theta})e^{-4\pi i\theta}Re^{2\pi i\theta}i2\pi d\theta\\
&=-2\pi iR^{2}P'(a),
\end{align*}
where $z=a+Re^{2\pi i\theta}$ is the parametrized curve.

Comment: Could you give some more details about how do you get from $\int_{C}$$P(z)$$\frac{\bar{z-a}}{z-a}$$dz$ to the next step?

Comment: The parametrized to $\dfrac{\overline{z-a}}{z-a}$ is something like $e^{-4\pi i\theta}$, and $dz$ is of $e^{2\pi i\theta}d\theta$, so the product is then $e^{2\pi i\theta}d\theta$, and if we expand the polynomial $P(z)=P(a)+P'(a)(z-a)+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n!}P^{(n)}(a)(z-a)^{n}$, we pick up the term $P'(a)(z-a)$ because for other terms, after parametrized, together with the product of $e^{2\pi i\theta}$, there is still some multiple of $e^{2\pi i\theta}$ left, and the integral to that is zero.

Comment: Actually that trick needs much justifications, that is no more than the classic formula that $d(uv)=udv+vdu$.

Comment: Yes. I deleted that comment since I figured it out, but it is nice to see that you confirm this! thank you!

Comment: why do you let $z=a+Re^{2\pi i\theta}$, why is that not $z=a+Re^{i\theta}$?

Comment: Yes, essentially they are, then the domain of integration is $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: Oh! Got you! Thank you!

Comment: Okay. I have gone thought most of your proof, and it makes great sense to me. But could you explain more about why do you choose $P^{'}(a)(z-a)$? I understand you used Taylor expansion and I understand $P(a)$ will go to $0$ after integrate since it will multiply $e^{2\pi i\theta}$, but how do I treat other terms?

Comment: For other terms, like $(z-a)^{2}$, after parametrised, it is $e^{4\pi i\theta}$, and so after multiplied with $e^{-2\pi i\theta}$, the left is $e^{2\pi i\theta}$, but the integral of this from $0$ to $1$ is simply zero.

Comment: Okay! I finished the proof. Thank you so much for your patient help!!